# Sample SAML request

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml, saml-2.0

I am trying to send SAML request to a URL using below format xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://tawtheeq.sa/mybank1/ReceiveSAMLResponse" Destination="https://tawtheeq.sa/identity-gateway/ReceiveSAMLRequest" ForceAuthn="false" ID="_964484d741502e19a0b148d478a64050" IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2018-06-04T12:46:07.860Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Version="2.0">
<saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">MyBank1
</saml:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
  <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
  <ds:Reference URI="#_964484d741502e19a0b148d478a64050">
    <ds:Transforms>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ds saml samlp"/></ds:Transform>
    </ds:Transforms>
    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <ds:DigestValue>B99CKUkHBSVelX86anIYMPaktnw=</ds:DigestValue>
  </ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>
  G99wkwUJfBUAV06ll6xATNWdf+JnAzdr2RZcJ2+l5DWY6sboj5+hh93qFO6QQjnd+hN/Wqzb6yAwyt8qnGUaJRHAf/LWClTcTsAGKbB1UpIAVLK11hjaeRnlQLBTBQXhzcASdWTwOH9CpgRwJLyKK8C7
</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo>
   <ds:X509Data>
    <ds:X509Certificate>
      MIIDaTCCAlGgAwIBAgIEB/lEIzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBlMQswCQYDVQQGEwJzYTEPMA0GA1UECBMGcml5YWRoMQ8wDQYDVQQHEwZyaXlhZGgxETAPBgNVBAoTCG15LWJhbmsxMQ0wCwYDVQQLEwRlcnNzMRIwEAYDVQQDEwlsb2NhbGhvc3QwHhcNMTgwMjA1MTQzNzI0WhcNMTkwMTMxMTQzNzI0WjBlMQswCQYDVQQGEwJzYTEPMA0GA1UECBMGcml5YWRoMQ8wDQYDVQQHEwZyaXlhZGgxETAPBgNVBAoTCG15LWJhbmsxMQ0wCwYDVQQLEwRlcnNzMRIwEAYDVQQDEwlsb2NhbGhvc3QwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3
    </ds:X509Certificate>
  </ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"/>
<samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
<saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
</samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

I used ComponentPro library to create SAML fil and sign it using my certificate file p.12 file but still can't access the IDP with correct request.

Here is my method to create SAML file and post it to the url.

```
    private void SendTawtheeqRequest()
    {
        string ConsumerServiceUrl = "https://tawtheeq.sa:8443/identity-gateway-test/ReceiveSAMLRequest";

        // Create a SAML response object.
        var samlResponse = new Response();

        // Assign the consumer service url.
        //samlResponse.Id = "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        samlResponse.Destination = ConsumerServiceUrl;
        //samlResponse.IssueInstant = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var issuer = new Issuer(GetAbsoluteUrl("~/"));
        samlResponse.Issuer = issuer;
        samlResponse.Status = new Status(SamlPrimaryStatusCode.Success, null);
        var samlAssertion = new Assertion();
        samlAssertion.Issuer = issuer;

        // Use the local user's local identity.
        var subject = new Subject(new NameId(User.Identity.Name));
        var subjectConfirmation = new SubjectConfirmation(SamlSubjectConfirmationMethod.Bearer);
        var subjectConfirmationData = new SubjectConfirmationData();
        subjectConfirmationData.Recipient = ConsumerServiceUrl;
        subjectConfirmation.SubjectConfirmationData = subjectConfirmationData;
        subject.SubjectConfirmations.Add(subjectConfirmation);
        samlAssertion.Subject = subject;

        // Create a new authentication statement.
        var authnStatement = new AuthnStatement();
        authnStatement.AuthnContext = new AuthnContext();
        authnStatement.AuthnContext.AuthnContextClassRef = new AuthnContextClassRef(SamlAuthenticationContext.Password);
        samlAssertion.Statements.Add(authnStatement);
        samlResponse.Assertions.Add(samlAssertion);


        //Signing created xml document
        var encryptingCert = new X509Certificate2(@"my_bank1_signed.p12");


        var Key = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)encryptingCert.PrivateKey;

        // Sign the SAML response with the certificate.
        samlResponse.Sign(Key, encryptingCert);
        // Send the SAML response to the service provider.

        Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        samlResponse.SendHttpPost(Response.OutputStream, ConsumerServiceUrl, "10");
    }
```

I just need to know how to reach this format if any one has experience with SAML also I'd appreciate it if you can share articles with me about this topic.

Comment: In general (as I'm not  familiar with the mentioned library): As you want to send an SAML AuthnRequest to a so called 'SingleSignOn' endpoint you have to create a SAMLRequest rather than a SAMLResponse. 

Is there a special reason why you need to user such a lower-level SAML library?

You would have to implement all the SAMLReponse checking as well if you want to build a SAMLv2 compliant ServiceProvider. That's quite some effort.

Comment: FWIW, please see cheated.by.safabyte.net which shows Component Pro likely represents the latest incarnation of stolen SAML software. TY